# Find last element in std::vector which satisfies a condition

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, stl-algorithm

I have this requirement to find the last element in the vector which is smaller than a value.

Like find_first_of but instead of first i want last. 
I searched and found that there is no find_last_of but there is find_first_of.

Why is that so? Is the standard way is to use find_first_of with reverse iterators?

Comment: Yes, use reverse iterators.

Answer (score 21):

Use [reverse iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,42,42,63};
  auto result = std::find_if(v.rbegin(), v.rend(),
                             [](int i) { return i == 42; });

  std::cout << std::distance(result, v.rend()) << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49b878f9261deeb3).

With C++20 ranges, that would become

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,42,42,63};
    auto result = std::ranges::find_if(v | std::views::reverse,
                                       [](int i) { return i == 42; });

    std::cout << std::distance(result, v.rend()) << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T3bd1Y7s1).

Comment: last line should be std::cout << std::distance( result, v.rend() ) << '\n';

Comment: @Akshay that will result in a negative number, I want the distance to the beginning of the array.

Comment: This won't compile. You cannot compare an iterator and a reverse iterator.

Comment: The linked demo contained the correct code. I aligned the code in the post.

Comment: Can this somehow be done with `std::ranges`?

Answer (score 7):

This is how it is done with reverse iterators:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {2,3,10,5,7,11,3,6};  

//below outputs '3':
std::cout << *(std::find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [](int i) { return i < 4; }));
```

Comment: You might want to check result before derefencing it in normal code.

Comment: Sure. Above is for illustrative purposes only

Comment: Um, what if the test was not i<4 but i<1? How do you detect whether a match is found?

Comment: Yeah as @Jarod42 points out the result needs checking. If a match isn’t found you get `vec.rend()` as your result (which shouldn’t be dereferenced with `*`)

Answer (score 3):

Just one thing. Be careful with the predicate if you're looking to find the tail-end of the range which includes the predicated element:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // finds the reverse iterator pointing at '2'
    // but using base() to convert back to a forward iterator
    // also 'advances' the resulting forward iterator.
    // in effect, inverting the sense of the predicate to 'v >= 3'
    auto iter = std::find_if(std::make_reverse_iterator(x.end()),
                 std::make_reverse_iterator(x.begin()),
                 [](auto& v) { return v < 3; }).base();

    std::copy(iter,
              x.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

result:

```
3, 4, 5,
```

Answer (score 0):

From ZenXml:

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator, class T> inline
BidirectionalIterator find_last(const BidirectionalIterator first, const 
BidirectionalIterator last, const T& value)
{
    for (BidirectionalIterator it = last; it != first;) 
    //reverse iteration: 1. check 2. decrement 3. evaluate
    {
        --it; //

        if (*it == value)
            return it;
    }    
    return last;
}
```