# Is there a function like lower_bound that returns the last value instead of the first?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

For example, if I have a sorted array

```
{1,1,1,1,1,4,5}
```

and I want to know the rightmost index of `1`, is there a function that will allow me to do that? (Apart from reverse sorting the array)

Comment: [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)?

Comment: `std::upper_bound - 1`

Comment: I did consider upper_bound but it does not accomplish what I want to do.

Comment: @Justin Wouldn't that give him the index of 5?

Comment: [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165432/find-last-element-in-stdvector-which-satisfies-a-condition)?

Comment: You can't always decrease the index by one

Comment: Use upper_bound and conditionally decrease the index by one

Comment: @Default Does that also work with array?

Comment: Like [std::string::find_last_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of)?

Comment: @JoannaJoa, All iterator-based interfaces work with arrays.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Turning the int into string would be extra, but I am searching for the int version of find_last_of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
auto p = std::equal_range( std::begin(v), std::end(v), 1 );
if( p.first != p.second ) {
    auto it = p.second - 1;
    //...
}
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/2ww3nR)

Answer (score 1):

There's none so you should craft one on your own.

```
template<class Ctr, class Elem> auto rightmost(Ctr &&c, Elem &&e) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    auto b{begin(c)};
    auto retVal{std::upper_bound(b, end(c), e)};
    return retVal == b? b : --retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 6> data({2,2,2,2,4,7});

    auto it = std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 2);
    int index = std::distance(data.begin(), it) - 1;

    std::cout << "index for last '2' is " << index << std::endl;
}
```

output:

`index for last '2' is 3`